# What is a regex for Twitter-like names?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, regex, ruby-on-rails-3

I have been coding for a while but never had the need for regular expressions until recently. I need to do a regular expression that accepts usernames as Twitter does. Basically, I want to allow one underscore at a time. There can be more than one underscore in a name but these should not be consecutive characters. Alphanumeric characters are also allowed. But numbers cannot start a name.

Names such as

- _myname67
- myname67
- my_name
- _my_67_name_

are valid but

- 94myname
- __myname
- my__name
- my name

are not valid.

I have played with [Rubular](http://rubular.com) and come up with a couple regexes:

- `/^[^0-9\s+](_?[a-z0-9]+_?)+$/i`
- `/^([a-z_?])+$/i`

The problem I keep running into is that these match more than one underscores.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the following `^([a-zA-Z](_?[a-zA-Z0-9]+)*_?|_([a-zA-Z0-9]+_?)*)$`

I've separated two cases: the word starts with a letter, and starts with an underscore. If you don't want to allow names consisting of one symbol only replace the `*` with `+`.

maerics's solution has one problem, it doesn't capture names that have `_` on the second place, such as `m_yname`

Comment: +1, but this one allows for a username of `_` which is not ideal.

Answer (score 10):

*Edited*

```
a = %w[
    _myname67
    myname67
    my_name
    _my_67_name_
    94myname
    __myname
    my__name
    my\ name
    m_yname
]

p a.select{|name| name =~ /\A_?[a-z]_?(?:[a-z0-9]_?)*\z/i}
# => ["_myname67", "myname67", "my_name", "_my_67_name_", "m_yname"]
```

You should use `(  )` only for substrings that you want to capture. `(?: )` is used for groupings that you do not want to capture. It is a good practice to use it whenever you do not need to refer particularly to that substring. It also makes the regex run faster.

Comment: succinct indeed. but as much as I would like to vote this as the right answer, it doesn't match the test string introduced by Hrant Khachatrian, "m_yname". However, this teaches me something new. Please explain the ?: expression you have.

Comment: There was a problem in the regex as pointed out by Yasky. I fixed it.

Comment: How do I include names starting with numbers too but not allow names containing only numbers.

Answer (score 1):

Some things are really hard to express using only regular expressions, and are generally write-only (that is, there's no way to read and understand them lately). You can use a simpler regexp (like the two ones you managed to write) and check for double underscores in your Ruby code. It doesn't hurt:

`if username =~ /^[^0-9](_?[a-z0-9]+_?)+$/i and username.count('__') == 0 then ...`

Comment: That doesn't work: multiple underscores that are NOT consecutive will fail here, which doesn't conform to the OP's requirements. (-1)

Comment: yeah, but it's still a good approach- I edited the answer to be username.count('__') > 0 which addresses the defect you mention...at least if count() works as I'm assuming it does.

Comment: No it doesn't (though I stupidly voted to approve the edit). You want it to be equal to zero.

Comment: ha well I just reedited since I realized it was screwy anyway! Serves me right for trying to fix an answer in a language I'm not too familiar with. I'll just give up now, I probably screwed it up again :P

Comment: Yes, I'm sorry, I had just read the post too too quickly. Fixed now, and thanks Brian.

Answer (score 1):

This seems to work:

```
/^(_|([a-z]_)|[a-z])([a-z0-9]+_?)*$/i
```

*Updates*: corrected for numeral constraints and case.

Comment: It's just an example to show the OP how to handle the consecutive-underscore issue.

Comment: @sawa this checks for an underscore or an alphabet before an underscore or an alphabet only at the initial position. It should pass.

Comment: an 'i' after the regex will take care of the case insensitivity

Answer (score 0):

Some problems can't be solved with just one regular expression... especially when you want to check for the absence of a pattern as well as the presence of another pattern.

Sometimes it is better (and definitely more readable) to break your conditions down into multiple regular expressions and match against each of them in turn.

In addition to your regular expressions to check for valid characters, you should also use a regular expression to check for the presence of two underscores, and then INVERT that result (that is, throw out the name if it MATCHES the pattern).

Comment: Or you can use @sawa's answer, which does the job in a single (but much harder to read) regex.

Comment: I think your answer would imply that it cannot be done with one regex. In the second sentence, you have the word `better`, which implies that there is a non-better way to do it, but is not strong enough to exclude the implication of the first sentence.

Comment: Fair point, though I think you're being far too literal in your parsing. Edited.

Answer (score 0):

```
/^[A-Za-z_]([A-Za-z0-9]+_?)+$/
```

Comment: Lord knows why. Rubular thinks this works great though [edit - well apart from the case of "m_yname" brought up by Hrant]. Many thanks